# Retrieving data from a Pendrive not containing file system

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

My friend gave me a pendrive with important data on it(did not do  backup) to retrieve. When we connect pendrive to USB I get the message: The volume does not contain a recognized file system and system asks to format it which obviously I cannot do(I do not want to loose).

Is there any way to repair it or get the data from the pendrive?

My system is: Windows 7 64-bit, but the error first occured on my friend's Windows XP 32-bit.

EDIT: The error is on the both systems, I got this pendrive because of that error-> my friend asked me to repair it.

Photo rec did not find anything.

EDIT2: WonderShare does not find any files,EasyUS Data Recovery cannot even use that pendrive(cause the recovery program uses windows explorer to select the file and the windows explorer does not let select that USB drive

My mistake EasyUS Data Recovery in recover partition mode sees the pendrive but did recover 0 files.

Comment: Do you see this error message on Win 7 as well or is it only on WinXP? If only on XP -> check if the file system is ExFat.

Comment: And to further mnmc comments, if you can see the data, back it up! It could be much simpler to zip it and email it!

Comment: The error is on the both systems, I got this pendrive because of that error-> my friend asked me to repair it.

Comment: Since you receive error message about file system - we can assume that Windows recognized the device. Therefore i would use one of the tools recommended here http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9224577/6_data_recovery_tools_for_SD_cards_USB_drives_and_more to try to retrieve the data that is not corrupted.

Comment: Recuva says:cannot read boot sector for this pendrive (I still did not formatted it)

Comment: Photorec does not find anything

Comment: @RobertKilar try this one: http://www.easeus.com/resource/drive/usb-flash-drive.htm or probably better this one: http://www.wondershare.com/disk-utility/usb-flash-drive-recovery.html

Comment: @mnmnc WonderShare does not find any files,EasyUS Data Recovery cannot even use that pendrive(cause the recovery program uses windows explorer to select the file and the windows explorer does not let select that USB drive)

Answer (score 0):

Grab a Linux LiveCD.  The best one for Linux beginners is Ubuntu, this has support for USB auto-mount.  Once you have booted into the LiveCD, connect the drive.  Even without a recognizable file system, the Linux OS should be able to detect and allow access to the data.